# Can someone help me improve a question about the v8-profiler?

Tags: support, specific-question

Well I asked a question on SO, which isn't answered for quite some time. - Now today I noticed it received a downvote. So apparently it is "not a good question". While that might be true, I really do like to get an answer.

So for that reason I ask now here: how can I improve a question?

The question which is a problem is: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48692051/how-to-use-v8-profiler-in-webstorm-in-a-sailsjs-server-application)

It shows what I've done to create the problem. It shows exactly the full error I get (which admittedly isn't really much, but that's also why I ask the question I can't seem to find anything about that error anywhere).

The only thing I can think of is that it is "too localized". But when I go to the websites for the specific tools they refer to "stackoverflow" to answer questions; as their official help channel.

Comment: Have you proven that this is a problem with your code by trying with a separate much simpler project? Have you tried eliminating any of your project to rule out possible causes? Both are rather important debugging steps that should be included in your question.

Comment: @KevinB While I could do that, I mainly just want to know what that status code means - then I can target the problem directly instead of blindly removing/adding one library at a time.

Comment: Bluntly, I don't see a direct problem with your question as posed. You're asking how to use a profiling tool, and any comments/questions/concerns related to the code under profiling scope are irrelevant.

Comment: @Makoto Maybe it's due to me being not a native English speaker but: "However the moment i try to run this custom route I get an error  `Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`" - I kind of see this as a "problem". I'll try stressing the error further.

Comment: eh, strictly speaking, yes, but it's just an error code. on it's own it isn't all that helpful.

Comment: In reality I'm trying to distill this to the base requirements.  You're asking about how to use a development tool.  You've stated what's happened when you run it.  I *presume* that this snippet is enough to replicate the same error (if it isn't then that's one spot to start with).

Comment: Which is why I ask the question. I don't get anymore than that, it just quits with that error code without any exception at all. Well once I find some time I'll create the most simplistic example I guess. (Should I delete and recreate or modify? - I have a feeling this occurs outside any library anyways)

Comment: Stack Overflow does not control *who* points to their site, and very little influence on *how*. If the wording on the help pages of these tools is ambiguous, ask a question here on Meta if someone with enough clout can approach them.

Comment: C0000005 is an access violation error code. This shouldn't happen in a memory-managed language like JS so in all probability there is a bug in the tools you're using. Report it to the maintainers.